# sscanf not scanning in the elements from string properly

Tags: c, string

I have created the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

const double PI = 3.14159;

int main()
{
    char str[120];
    double distance, azimuth;
    double delta_x = 0;
    double delta_y = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        return -1;
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp); //skip first line

    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp)) {
        if (strcmp("Dig here!", str) == 0) 
            break;
        printf(str);
        sscanf(str, "go %f feet by azimuth %f\n", &distance, &azimuth);
        printf("distance %f azimuth %f\n", distance, azimuth);
        delta_y += distance * sin(azimuth * (PI/180));
        delta_x += distance * cos(azimuth * (PI/180));
    }

    printf("%d %d", delta_x, delta_y);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

**input.txt** looks something like this

```
Stand at the pole with the plaque START

go 500 feet by azimuth 296

go 460 feet by azimuth 11

Dig here!
```

However the output gives

```
go 500 feet by azimuth 296

distance 0.000000 azimuth 0.000000
```

I'm sure it's a dumb error I am missing but I can't seem to find it, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `%lf` instead `%f` for `double` in `sscanf`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY that fixed it thanks! would you mind telling my why that works?

Comment: Read [sscanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

Comment: Because `%lf` is the correct conversion specifier for `double`; `%f` is for `float`.

Comment: @David Bowling thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `"%f"` format specifier of [`scanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) is for `float` type:

> **f** – Matches an optionally signed **floating-point number**; the next pointer must be a pointer to `float`.

If you wish to parse a `double` type then use the `l` format specifier in combination with `f`:

> **l** – Indicates either that the conversion will be one of **d**, **i**, **o**, **u**, **x**, **X**, or **n** and the next pointer is a pointer to a `long int` or `unsigned long int` (rather than `int`), or that the conversion will be one of **e**, **f**, or **g** and the next pointer is a pointer to `double` (rather than `float`).

So, you should change your format string as follows:

```
sscanf(str, "go %lf feet by azimuth %lf\n", &distance, &azimuth);
printf("distance %lf azimuth %lf\n", distance, azimuth);
```

---

Note that [`fgets`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) may contain trailing `'\n'`, in other words if a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. Therefore before you compare the input coming from `fgets` against `"Dig here!"`, you have to remove the newline first.

There is many options to do this, in the comments below you can see a good one or you can use the following approach with [`strcspn`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcspn) function:

```
str[strcspn(str, "\r\n")] = '\0'; /* works for any combination of CR and LF */

if(strcmp("Dig here!", str) == 0) 
    break;
```

Comment: Also note that `if(strcmp("Dig here!", str) == 0)` is unlikely to match because of the trailing newline.

Comment: @chqrlie, thanks for the suggestion, I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: There is no guarantee the final line will contain an *end-of-line*. Better `len = strlen(str); if (len && str[len-1] == '\n') str[--len] = 0;` then compare `if (strcmp("Dig here!", str) == 0)`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, thanks for clarification. I modified my answer using another approach but referred to yours as well.